# removing certain elements from a string

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to change the following content to a string in php so that the names come out as this

```
itai,bliss
```

instead of this which is showing in my blade file

```
"["itai","bliss"]"
```

ive tried to do this in my controller but its showing an invalid result.

```
$minute = Minutes::find($id);
$minuteSlash = $minute->attendances;
$attendees = substr($minuteSlash, 2, -2);
```

is there a way i can do this

Comment: Check ```implode()``` function

Comment: Show more about where the data comes from and how you are displaying it?

Comment: Is this a json column in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can solve your problem.

```
$attendees = str_replace(["\"", "[", "]"], "", $minuteSlash);
```

Thanks